# Change the departure point of a branch in Egit

Tags: egit

I have the following situation :

```
branch A|   branch master
        |   |
        |   |
        |   |   branch B
        |   |   |<------B2
        |   |___|<------B1
        |   |<--------some commits (*) in B and in master, but not in A
        \___|
            |
```

I created a branch B from master but that was a mistake, I should have created B from A, and not from master.

So my initial thought was to Rebase B onto A.
The problem with this approach is that the commits `(*)` are also rebased in B, which I don't want.
So I wanted to use "cherry-picking" to duplicate the commits from B (after the divergent point with master) into A.
But since Egit uses Interactive Rebase to do that, the problem is the same. The commits (*) are present in A.

Basically, I want to apply the functional changes introduced by B1 and B2 in the branch A, without the changes introduced by (*).
The only solution that I found is to manually `'create Patch'` for B1 and apply it in A, and then `'create Patch'` for B2, and apply it in A.

Is there another way to easily do what I want to achieve using Egit ?

Comment: Note that the cherry-pick behavior is a regression in EGit, see [bug 447115](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=447115).

Comment: Alright then if cherry pick is repaired, it would be a solution to my problem.  Is it the right way to do what I want with regular plain git ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you want to do in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

In the command line:

```
git rebase --onto a last-ignored-commit b
```

or

```
git rebase --onto a first-wanted-commit~ b
```

If you are already on branch-b you do not need to specify that as the last argument. Both commands evaluate to the same thing. The tilde (~) means find the first parent. Therefore last-ignored-commit and first-wanted-commit~ both refer to the same commit.

Comment: I Wanted an egit answer, and not regular C get.

Comment: I understood from you comment that anything would do if there was no EGit solution. I generally only use EGit for tasks where a GUI is helpful such as Ineteractive Rebase and Git Staging. When it comes to many advanced commands EGit is not nearly as robust as the command line.

Comment: True, but it's getting there :)